# Xcode 8 beta: Testable names must be unique

Tags: swift, xcode

I installed Xcode 8 beta 3 and tried to convert the source files to Swift 3. Does not work as I get the following error every time:

> Testable names must be unique

Any idea what this means?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is there any duplicated `TestableReference` in your `.xcscheme` file? Please check the `BuildableName` duplication. Just delete the unnecessary `TestableReference`.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to convert my project until I added all the 'Test Schemes' in the drop down list (Manage Scheme and clic + button)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Active Scheme is selected for the target you are trying to convert.

Lets say you have a scheme called MyApp and a scheme named UITesting.  If the Swift code to be converted lives in UITesting, make sure that UITesting is the active scheme (in the upper left of Xcode window).  I got the reported error when MyApp was the active scheme.